# Is increase of entropy the driving force of surface tension?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, surface-tension

> ...These molecules have unbalanced forces such that they have net force
>   in downward direction. Thus they have practically least entropy and
>   maximum potential energy. Water molecules at the surface are pulled
>   inwards such that the surface is compressed with minimum surface area.
>   Thus every molecule on the surface of water have its intrinsic
>   tendency to move below to enjoy maximum entropy. (Spontaneous process)
>   This tendency leads to the surface of water to have minimum surface
>   area.(Definition of surface tension)  Hence most of the surface
>   tension is due to tendency of their surface molecules to gain maximum
>   entropy....

I copy this citation from the internet site Quora. Does anyone agree with this reasoning?

Is entropy increase the driving force of surface tension?

I am not asking for a yes or no. Any comment, amswer or link will be useful.

Comment: Have a read of this, if you haven't already...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension     3/4 of the page down, surface tension is dealt with in thermodynamic /entropy terms

Comment: As noted by @TáMéCeart, one has to dig a bit deeper in to the thermodynamics. Asking if I agree with the reasoning in some random passage on the internet probably doesn't get you anywhere. Is entropy increase the _sole_ driving force? No.

Comment: @JonCuster Except me, maybe other people want your lights on this matter and you can always write an answer instead of a dry no.

Comment: Any surface is associated with energy, which in cases of fluids is called surface tension. A system seeks a state of minimum energy consistent with its constraints. Therefore surface area becomes minimum possible, consistent with constraints on it. It can be shown that energy minimization is equivalent to entropy maximization (see _Thermodynamics_ by Callen). So I would say the quote is mostly right, but such vague statements are unhelpful, especially I don't know what they mean by "entropy of molecules". The entropy I am speaking of here is classical, and is a property of entire system.

Comment: @TáMéCeart Yes, the answer is a duplicate. I don't press anyone. I will put a bounty, instead.

Comment: Surface tension is the *free energy* (per unit area), in other words it has both an enthalpy and an entropy contribution, so Jon is right.

Comment: I wouldn't use entropy as driven force; it is only used for making a judgement if a process is possible. The driven force will be Newton's principal, minimum potential principal, and its thermodynamic equivalent free Gibbs energy.